# Controlling the position of angular material 2 autocomplete options panel

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-material2

I am trying to **control the position of angular material 2 autocomplete options panel** and place this panel in a separate div from the div of the actual input.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex="50">
    <form [formGroup]="formStatus.form">
      <div>
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput formControlName="title" placeholder="Titre">
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <div>
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput placeholder="Address" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="address">
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="50" style="background-color: palegreen">
    <!-- options panel should appear here in the palegreen div -->
    <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="addressFormatter">
      <md-option *ngFor="let address of addresses | async" [value]="address">
        {{ address.description }}
      </md-option>
    </md-autocomplete>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the options panel still appears right below the input and its position seems to be bound to that of the input...

Comment: Same issue with Datepicker...

Answer (score 2):

You can control the position of angular material 2 autocomplete options panel with the following code

```
::ng-deep .mat-autocomplete-panel{
  position: fixed !important;
  top:30% !important;
  left: 40%;
  right: 30%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  background-color: palegreen !important;
}
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  Please expand on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this exactly meets your requirements but you can control the position of `mat-calendar` and `mat-autocomplete-panel` by manipulating their parent classes. These overwritten classes need to sit level above the targeted component to take effect.

Example:

```
.mat-autocomplete-panel {
   position: fixed !important;
   top:30% !important;
   left: 40%;
   right: 30%;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
   background-color: palegreen !important;
}
```

Datepicker [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/iduBuX?p=preview)

Autocomplete [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RI7gDTM1fJEI5LLvxkHv?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the samples @Nehal ! Do you confirm CSS is the only way of achieving the separation?

Comment: Is there a CSS way to position the autocomplete panel in a given div instead of using a relative position?

Comment: Hi @balteo, I haven't found any way of changing css properties of md-autocomplete without tweaking its own associated css classes. That's the only solution I could come up with :(

Comment: Hi again Nehal. I am looking for a way to extend the component and use my own template...

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to current solutions provided by @ferralucho and @Nehal

`::ng-deep` as @ferralucho suggested was required for me to affect the parent component class.

I wanted to show my autocomplete options panel further down from my  because I had a wrapper div around the input box. The following worked:

```
::ng-deep .mat-autocomplete-panel {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
```